# How to whitelist IP addresses for AWS ElasticBeanStalk Application Health Check?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, health-monitoring, elastic-load-balancer

I use an IP whitelist in the application CORS configuration.

Unfortunately, this means that Application Health Check pings to the ElasticBeanStalk application fail with:

```
Error: Bad Request: Invalid origin
```

The IP addresses appear to be dynamic.

**How do I dynamically query for the HealthCheck ping IP addresses, so I can include them in the whitelist?**

AWS seems to have multiple health checkers, and the IP ranges seem to differ for each. Found the Route53 health checker IPs in the aws cli [route53:get-checker-ip-ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/get-checker-ip-ranges.html), but cannot find an equivalent end-point for ElasticBeanStalk (or ElasticLoadBalancer; which the ElasticBeanStalk application health check appears to use).

Deployment environment: AWS Elastic BeanStalk with 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.0 running Node.js

Comment: Hmm...the ElasticBeanStalk ping is originating from the IP of the underlying EC2 instance, not a separate IP list as with the Route53 health check.

Comment: Hmmm.  ELBs check your instance from other IP addresses on the subnets where the balancer is defined, but they set the `Host` header to the instance address.

Comment: You're right, the addresses are all `172.`, which are private (172.16 - 172.32): https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html. Hackwork around is including `172.x.x.x` in the white list, but I'd still really like to know a proper solution.

Comment: They're all in the range of your VPC IPs.  Balancers don't have fixed IPs, though they can go days, weeks, or months without changing... but you don't want to pin it down to exactly what the balancer is using now.  It's the subnets your balancer is assigned to.

Comment: In that case, any idea how to dynamically query the IP of the ELB for whitelisting?

Comment: You really should avoid that, because you will get burned badly when they change, since that's outside your control and is most likely to occur at exactly the worst time: when the balancer scales out, up, or down.  You can find them under "Network Interfaces" in the left hand pane in the EC2 console, and with `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces`.